# How to return month number and year using javascript in YY-MM-DD format?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date from my textbox of '2015-02-17' (yy-mm-dd) format. Now I want to return only the month number of **2** and a year of **2015**. I can't do it correctly using getMonth() function.

I tried the following:

```
 // Get date value from the textbox
 var t_date = $("#t_date").val();    // 2015-01-17     
 alert(t_date.getMonth());
```

It does not show the alert box. Seems like my code is not valid.
Please help. Thanks

Comment: Show us what you tried, and what was not correct about it

Comment: You may use momentjs for data formatting: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: try `str.split("-")` and get the value of first and second array

Comment: You are giving `getMonth()` a string value as an input, that will not work, because it expects a date value. Try using the `split` method or change the input values to a proper date format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var t_date = new Date($("#t_date").val()); 
alert(t_date.getMonth() + 1); // because months are zero based.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the `substring`, since you know the format of your day. This way you will avoid to create a `Date` object and then use its method to get the month and the year.

```
var month = input.substring(5,7);

var yaer = input.substring(0,4);
```

Where `input` is the text of your input element. Please try the following snippet.

```js
// Get the value of date
var input = document.getElementById("date").value;

// Get the month.
var month = input.substring(5,7);

// Get the year.
var year = input.substring(0,4);


alert("month: "+month+" year: "+year);
```

```html
<input id="date" type="text" value="2015-02-17"/>
```

If you want these numbers to be integers, you can use the `parseInt` function. For instance in case of month, you can try this:

```
var month = parseInt(input.substring(5,7));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split on `-` and you can get what you want using the index

```
var arr = $("#t_date").val().split('-');
console.log('Year:', arr[0], 'Month:', arr[1], 'Day:', arr[2]);
```

or just pass the `$('#t_date').val()` to the `Date` constructor, but you could simply use the above approach without instantiating a `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know the month for Javascript is Zero-based. Meaning, Jan is 00, Feb is 01, march is 02.
What you need to do is to make the newly created date a variable(var date = newDate(2015, 02,17)); and make another variable(var month=date.getMonth()); and (var year=date.getFullYear());

Answer (score 0):

First, the text input value is just a string, not a real date. A string value doesn't 'know' the `getMonth` method. So, you'll have to convert it to a `Date` instance, using `new Date([value])`<sup>**1**</sup>. Second, the months array of a date (retrieved with `getMonth`) is zero based, so you have to add 1 to it to make it a 'human' month number.

<sup>**1**</sup> Note: in this case the string is valid input for the `Date` constructor (yyyy-mm-dd), but that may not always be the case. For example, a Europan date string like `'15-01-2015'` (dd-mm-yyyy) wouldn't be valid. [See also ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax)

```js
showMY();
$('#show').on('click', showMY);

function showMY(e) {
  var t_date = new Date($("#t_date").val());
  if (isNaN(t_date)) {
    $('#result').html('Invalid format. Can\'t create a date from ' +
                      $("#t_date").val());
  } else {
    $('#result').html( 'Month number and year: '+ 
                      (t_date.getMonth() +  1) + ', ' + 
                      t_date.getFullYear() );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="t_date" value="2015-01-17"> <button id="show">show month/year</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```